# Symfony 5 cache:clear warning on non-existing controller anymore

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm dealing with a strange behaviour :
I moved/renamed some controllers in my Symfony 5 app across dev time

But when I want to clear the cache :

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`

is working without warning and :

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

is working fine but show some warning  like :

`09:14:12 WARNING   [php] Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/dev/project/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/Bundle/WelcomeCustomController.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') ["exception" => ErrorException { …}]`

All warnings about controllers who does not exists anymore and are obviously not used in dependency injection or whatever..

While I have clear the cache manually est re-run cache:clear, how can Symfony check about non existing Controllers and how can i fix this ?!!

Comment: Have you checked that you're not referencing them in some service config files? Or imported them with `use` in some other files?
Which file is trying to include the controller? Can you check that by adding -vvv to the console command?

Comment: It didn't show more explainations but "composer dump-autoload" like Adrien Lamotte said solved the warning problem! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

When you delete/rename a controller, try to dump composer autoload:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: That's it ! Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Glad it worked for you @dowchat , remember to validate the answer ;)

Comment: Yes i did of course but as i'm a new member i have to reach reputation 15 before my validation is effective ! (that's what i read when i validated your answer ^^)